# Entity get relations in one query and cannot get in another

Tags: c#, entity, asp.net-identity

```
    public ActionResult Users()
    {
        var user = _userRepository.Find(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(user);
    }

    public ActionResult CashAccountInfo(int id)
    {
        var result = _cashAccountRepository.Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return View(result);
    }
```

When i debug **Users()** i get [image]

where i have AppUser
but when i debug **CashAccountInfo(int id)**
i get  [image]

without AppUser

Find method from Repository

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
```

Please help why in one query get entity but in another cannot get

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using entity framework, this is a Lazy Loading issue. Maybe add an Include to your calls when using your context.

For example:

```
context.Include(x => x.AppUser).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

If this isn't the case or you're not using entity framework then you need to show the code for your repository methods.

Comment: I think with include would work, but i want to know why in one query get by relations and in another didn`t get.
In repository i use the one method so result must be the same.

Comment: Why don't you update the question with the code from your `_userRepository` and `_cashAccountRepository` `Find` methods. It's the only way anyone could give a definite answer.